# Calculate the number of people occupied at each time interval

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparative-review

The following scripts calculate a list with the number of people occupied at each time interval.
The intervals are defined by the timestamps of two consecutive events that come from the sorted list `events_timeline`.
Also, `start_ts` and `end_ts` are taking into account for intervals calculation and for each event, one person is occupied.

input data to be used in the following scripts:

```py
MINIMUM_EVENT_INTERVAL = 1
start_ts = 1598939760.0
end_ts = 1598939792.0
events_timeline = [(1598939761.0, 's'), (1598939771.0, 's'), (1598939781.0, 'e'),
                   (1598939791.0, 'e')]  # 's' and 'e' denote start and end event respectively
```

1st approach:

```py
people_occupied = []
start_events = 0
end_events = 0

num_events_timeline = len(events_timeline)

if events_timeline[0][0] - start_ts >= MINIMUM_EVENT_INTERVAL:
    people_occupied.append(0)

for index, (ts, event) in enumerate(events_timeline):
    if event == 's':
        start_events += 1
    else:
        end_events += 1

    if index != num_events_timeline - 1 and ts == events_timeline[index + 1][0]:
        continue

    if index == num_events_timeline - 1 and end_ts - ts < MINIMUM_EVENT_INTERVAL:
        break

    people_occupied.append(start_events - end_events)

print(f'1st approach: {people_occupied}')
```

2nd approach:

```py
currently_occupied = 0
people_occupied = []

if events_timeline[0][0] - start_ts >= MINIMUM_EVENT_INTERVAL:
    people_occupied.append(0)

for (start_time, event_type), (end_time, _) in zip(events_timeline[:-1], events_timeline[1:]):
    if event_type == 's':
        currently_occupied += 1
    else:
        currently_occupied -= 1

    if end_time > start_time:
        people_occupied.append(currently_occupied)

if end_ts - events_timeline[-1][0] >= MINIMUM_EVENT_INTERVAL:
    people_occupied.append(0)

print(f'2nd approach: {people_occupied}')
```

Both approaches do the job, but which one of them should be preferred and why?

Comment: Please describe only code purpose in the title.

Comment: @Caridorc you maybe have already seen - the title has been updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, at the edge of your program you shouldn't be entering datetimes as timestamp numeric literals, but as human-legible datetimes. On the inside of your program, you *also* shouldn't be processing datetimes as numeric timestamps, but instead as well-typed `datetime.datetime` instances.

The interior of your loop ignores `MINIMUM_EVENT_INTERVAL` and only pays attention to that at the bounds of your event sequence. This seems unlikely to be a good idea. Ideally, you would pay attention to that minimum for *every* event, and treat your bounds `start_ts` and `end_ts` the same way that you treat everything in your main timeline.

Generally I think your second approach using `zip` is preferable, but it isn't enough. You should write well-typed functions. Iterator functions are a convenient way to capture your logic.

### Suggested

This (intentionally) isn't exactly equivalent in terms of logic, but since all of your timestamps already meet the interval minimum, the output is the same.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from typing import Iterable, Iterator, Literal, Sequence

MINIMUM_EVENT_INTERVAL = timedelta(seconds=1)


Event = tuple[
    datetime,
    # 's' and 'e' denote start and end event respectively
    Literal['s', 'e'],
]


def get_events_with_endpoints(
    start_ts: datetime,
    end_ts: datetime,
    events: Iterable[Event],
) -> Iterator[Event]:
    yield start_ts, 's'
    yield from events
    yield end_ts, 'e'


def get_occupied(events: Sequence[Event]) -> Iterator[int]:
    currently_occupied = 0

    for (start_time, _), (end_time, event_type) in zip(events[:-1], events[1:]):
        if end_time - start_time >= MINIMUM_EVENT_INTERVAL:
            yield currently_occupied
        if event_type == 's':
            currently_occupied += 1
        else:
            currently_occupied -= 1


def main() -> None:
    timeline = (
        (datetime(2020, 9, 1, 3, 26,  1), 's'),
        (datetime(2020, 9, 1, 3, 26, 11), 's'),
        (datetime(2020, 9, 1, 3, 26, 21), 'e'),
        (datetime(2020, 9, 1, 3, 26, 31), 'e'),
    )

    events = get_events_with_endpoints(
        start_ts=datetime(2020, 9, 1, 3, 26,  0),
        end_ts  =datetime(2020, 9, 1, 3, 26, 32),
        events=timeline,
    )

    print(tuple(get_occupied(tuple(events))))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Output

```
(0, 1, 2, 1, 0)
```